# Enterprise Architect: GetBaselines does not work in python

Tags: python, enterprise-architect

I've written a Python function to retrieve baselines from a PackageGUI:

```
def get_baselines(pkgguid):
    """ Get list of baselines for package """
    rep = win32com.client.Dispatch("EA.App").Repository
    rep.GetPackageByGuid(pkgguid) # Works
    print("pgkname: ", pkg.Name) # This works
    project = rep.GetProjectInterface() # Works
    print ("guid xml: ", project.GUIDtoXML(pkgguid), "GUID: ", pkgguid) # Works
    pkgxml = project.GetBaselines(project.GUIDtoXML(pkgguid)) # Throws Error
    print (pkgxml) # Not reached
```

This leads to the error:

```
File "C:\devel\EnterpriseArchitect\ea_scripts\dbops.py", line 44, in get_baselines
pkgxml = project.GetBaselines(project.GUIDtoXML(pkgguid))
File "<COMObject GetProjectInterface>", line 3, in GetBaselines
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1)
```

I have not used any Project Interface before, so possibly there is a mistake with the the input format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`project.GetBaselines` accepts two parameters of type String, and you only passed one parameter.
See [the documentation](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/project_2.html)

> GetBaselines (string PackageGUID, string ConnectString)
>
> String
>
> Notes: Returns a list (in XML format) of Baselines associated with the
> supplied Package GUID.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - PackageGUID: String - the GUID (in XML format) of the Package to get
>   Baselines for
> - ConnectString: String - not currently used

So you would need to call it like this:

```
pkgxml = project.GetBaselines(project.GUIDtoXML(pkgguid), "")
```

Comment: thank you. The "" was apparently lost after I found out that the pkgguid needs conversion to XML. Somehow I cannot accept the answer.

Comment: You might need to wait a certain amount of time before you can accept the question. Might be 24 hours; I'm not sure.